# NSIS script not installing in correct directory

Tags: nsis, system32, syswow64

I am trying to make an install script:

- on 32bits pc: tapi_32bits.tsp in `C:\windows\system32`
- on 64bits pc : tapi_64bits.tsp in `C:\Windows\System32` and tapi_32bits.tsp in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`

This is the script I wrote:

```
; The name of the installer
Name "TAPI Installer"

; The file to write
OutFile "TAPI Installer"

; The default installation directory
InstallDir $DESKTOP

;--------------------------------

; Install to the correct directory on 32 bit or 64 bit machines
Section
IfFileExists $WINDIR\SYSWOW64\*.* Is64bit Is32bit
Is32bit:
    ; Set output path to the installation directory.
    SetOutPath $SYSDIR

    ; Put file there
    File tapi_32bits.tsp

;   SectionEnd MessageBox MB_OK "32 bit"
        SetRegView 32
        StrCpy $INSTDIR "$PROGRAMFILES32\LANDesk\Health Check"
    GOTO End32Bitvs64BitCheck

Is64bit:
    ; install in  C:\Windows\System32
    SetOutPath $WINDIR\System32\

    ; file to put there
    File tapi_64bits.tsp

    ; install in C:\Windows\SysWOW64
    SetOutPath $WINDIR\SysWOW64

    ; file to put there
    File tapi_32bits.tsp


    ;SectionEnd MessageBox MB_OK "32 bit"
        SetRegView 32
        StrCpy $INSTDIR "$PROGRAMFILES32\LANDesk\Health Check"
        GOTO End32Bitvs64BitCheck    
    MessageBox MB_OK "64 bit"
        SetRegView 64
        StrCpy $INSTDIR "$PROGRAMFILES64\LANDesk\Health Check"

End32Bitvs64BitCheck:
SectionEnd
;--------------------------------
```

But on 64bits pc it  places both files (tapi_64bits.tsp and tapi_32bits.tsp) in the Syswow64 folder. The installer does say that it is installed in the correct folder but both files are  in the Syswow64 folder. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

NSIS is a 32 bit application so it is affected by [file redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You must use [x64.nsh](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Include/x64.nsh), it has code to detect WOW64 and disable redirection (Turn it back on as soon as possible). The other alternative is to extract to `$windir\sysnative` but that is more of a hack and does not work on XP 64.

Comment: seems ok sysnative is replaced by system32 on Win 7 x64

Comment: @Tanguy: No it is not! In a 64-bit app there is only %windir%\system32 and this contains the real 64-bit system files (32-bit system files are in SysWow64). In a 32-bit app %windir%\sysnative contains the 64-bit system files and %windir%\system32 contains the 32-bit system files...

Comment: On a 64bit system using a 32bit setup by nsis, using `DisableX64FSRedirection` with an output path of `$SYSDIR` - willplace my 64bit dll in the correct directory for a shared dll - jsut need to check for shared counter and if it already existed beforehand as to not replace it?

Comment: @PatrickArtner The library header can do the shared counter and 64-bit stuff for you.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work.

```
!include x64.nsh    
; Install to the correct directory on 32 bit or 64 bit machines
Section
${If} ${RunningX64}
; install in  C:\Windows\System32
SetOutPath $WINDIR\System32\

; file to put there
File tapi_64bits.tsp

; install in C:\Windows\SysWOW64
SetOutPath $WINDIR\SysWOW64

; file to put there
File tapi_32bits.tsp
${Else}
; Set output path to the installation directory.
SetOutPath $SYSDIR
; Put file there
File tapi_32bits.tsp
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```